# Double conditioning in probability

Tags: probability

The law of total probability says that if $E$ and $F$ partition the sample space then
$$P(A) = P(A \mid E)P(E) + P(A \mid F)P(F).$$
How do I make sense of
$$P(A \mid B) = P(A \mid B \mid E)P(E) + P(A \mid B \mid F)P(F),$$
specifically what $P(A \mid B \mid E)$ means? More particularly, I am working on computing
$$P(A \mid B \cup C)$$
where $B$ and $C$ are disjoint. Can I do
$$P(A \mid B \cup C) = P(A \mid B \cup C \mid B)P(B) + P(A \mid B \cup C \mid C)P(C)?$$

Comment: Try using the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that and look at it from this perspective. I just want to know how to interpret $P((A|B)|C)$

Comment: I have never seen that notation used. You probably mean $P(A \mid B \cap C)$. To find out what equalities this satisfies, again, just use the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: There can only be one slash separating the events from the conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> specifically what $P(A∣B∣E)$  means?

It does not mean anything; its nonsensible.   There can only be one slash separating the events from the condition.   The divider is not a set operator.

The Law of Total Probability states that if $E, F$ partitions $B$ : that is $B\cap E, B\cap F$ are disjoint and $B\subseteq (E\cup F)$ , then:

$$\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\mathsf P(A\mid B\cap E)\,\mathsf P(E\mid B)+\mathsf P(A\mid B\cap F)\,\mathsf P(F\mid B)$$

So since $B\cup C$ is partitioned by $B, C$ when $B, C$ are disjoint then:

$$\mathsf P(A\mid B\cup C)=\mathsf P(A\mid B)\,\mathsf P(B\mid B\cup C)+\mathsf P(A\mid C)\,\mathsf P(C\mid B\cup C)$$

Etc.